# Extension for safari that allows to block some keywords

Tags: productivity, safari

BlockSite is a practical extension for Chrome that allows blocking specific URLs and specific **terms**. So that if a web page contains blacklisted terms, the entire webpage gets obfuscated. Unfortunately, BlockSite is not available for Safari. Is there any good substitute or workaround that one can use?